# Which method of FacebookClient to be used to archive a message thread of a Facebook page?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, c#-4.0

By integrating FaceBook Page (using Page Access token), i am replying to the private messages of the users. 
At certain point of time, i want to move that message thread from Inbox to Archive, How that can be possible using Graph API ? 
I am referencing Facebook Version 6.0.10.0 and used FacebookClient class.

It would be great if you can guide me with the method which help me archive any message thread based on Message_Id

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Pretty sure that is not possible via API.

Comment: @CBroe Ok. Thanks